# Is Solr available for .Net?

Tags: .net, lucene, solr

I want to learn Solr. May I know some good tutorial/links for it?

Also, is Solr available for .NET?

Comment: Have you tried the SOLR home site (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)? Remember search engines are your friends!

Comment: Lazarus, FYI google brought me here.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you mean running the Solr server on .Net instead of Java, then no, there is no port. I've been trying to run it with [IKVM](https://github.com/ikvmnet/ikvm) [here](https://github.com/mausch/SolrIKVM) but it's low-priority to me so I can't put much time on it. It'd be great if someone can help out with this.

If you mean using/connecting to Solr from a .Net application, then yes, you can use [SolrNet](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) or [SolrSharp](http://solrsharp.codeplex.com/) for that.

I [blogged about this](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/10/untangling-mess-solr-solrnet-nhibernate.html) not long ago.

UPDATE: I made [significant progress with Solr + IKVM](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/02/running-solr-on-net.html).

Comment: We use an older version of SolrNet and it is very easy to follow and integrate.. I'd recommend it.

Comment: there seem to be a C# API for interoperation with Solr.. http://www.codeplex.com/solrsharp

Comment: Does either SolrSharp or SolrNet (or both) not use the RESTful interface to Solr, but rather some direct interop?

Comment: @soandos: Solr's interface is not RESTful. SolrNet only uses HTTP at the moment. There is an open issue to connect to SolrIKVM if you're interested in working on this: https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=69

Comment: It appears these client connectors (SolrNet, SolrSharp and MicroSolr) don't work anymore. They aren't updated for the newest version of Solr, so some calls don't work anymore.

Comment: @Jan_V : That's not correct. I'm the author of SolrNet and I'm still maintaining it. See https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/README.md#downloads

Comment: Strange, I got an error while doing a `Commit()` and the error log told me the `waitFlush` wasn't supported anymore in the latest version of Solr, which was called in the background. Maybe an error on my side, will check it soonish.

Comment: I see my error now. I used the Nuget Prerelease version of the libraries (`0.4.0-beta2`), thinking it would be kind of up-to-date, but it isn't. Now I've downloaded the `0.4.0.2002.zip` and referenced these assemblies and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Rodenburg created a C# API for interoperation with Solr. The API supports:

> Adding, updating and deleting documents from a solr index.
>   Configuration support for multiple solr instances.
>   Flags for Read/Write modes in support of solr replication.
>   Search queries that return strongly-typed objects
>   Support for facets

and more ... http://www.codeplex.com/solrsharp

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, there's at least one open source project on GitHub.

https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replicate the Lucene.NET database between several machines (in a master-slave disposition), so you can try Lucene Steroids, available at http://bitbucket.org/guibv/lucene.steroids.

This code is based on Solr shell scripts, and uses cwRsync to sync files.

Comment: You get a lot more from using Solr than just replicating. Think of e.g. creating facets.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to introduce my open-source library called LinqToSolr, which provides the functionality of building linq-queries to Solr.
Here is a [nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToSolr/) or browse [github project](https://github.com/DanielLavrushin/LinqToSolr)