# How can i use solr search in mvc.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr

I am working with **mvc.net 2.0**, **sql server 2005**.

Is it possible to implement Apache Solr search on this platform?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749314/is-solr-available-for-net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing Solr with .net web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800919/implementing-solr-with-net-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Lucene search, you could take a look at [Examine](http://examine.codeplex.com/) it's a non-enterprise Lucene search.

If you need your search as a service then use Solr, you'll need to install a [Solr server](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall). For that you'll need to install [Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat) or another servlet container and create a Solr instance.

Once you've done that you can [post XML fragments](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) from your code to create your index as you would normally perform HttpPost's. Then you use HttpGet requests to [search the index](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax).

Comment: how can i create solr instance... is it require any solr.dll if yes then how can i use it

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding Solr. Solr runs as a service in a seperate web application. You have to interface with it via HTTP like a website API.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Solr example site called Solrnet which you may be interested in.

Source code:
http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet

Wiki:
http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to use lucence. Solr is the client that you can use to query lucene and from what I know is that you donot need to build a client that specifically handles query calls to lucene. The beauty of solr is that it uses http calls to query lucene. So all you need is to use Solr to create your indexes via http calls. Lucene takes care of the back end processing of these calls.
Try http://www.lucidimagination.com/ you will find lots of examples. here

And you can download the Solr package from Apache site. You can set it up and simple use your browser to test the queries. It will take you some time to setup Solr, once you are through it you can test it very easly.