# Implementing Solr with .net web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, solr, lucene, lucene.net, solrnet

I'm about to implement Solr for search on NopCommerce based cart application. I would like to have an idea on the steps as how should I proceed with this. I have looked google for some help, but it didn't really helped. I found that there is an interface for .net for integrating this with .net applications, but not found any doc or tutorial on solr site.

I need your help in deciding the best approach to address this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [Solr Tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_0/tutorial.html) on the Solr Site. And as far as setting up a site that is accessible from an ASP.NET MVC web site, I would recommend implementing the [SolrNet](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) client and using the [SolrSampleApp](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/master/SampleSolrApp) as a starting point.

Comment: for me when i try to run SolrSampleApp in visual studio express for web 2013, it gives me error about using SolrNet;, that the refenence is missing. And when i use NuGet to receive a new reference i get other errors.

This could be that its made for .net 3.5. Do you know if theres av new version for mvc 4 or 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do it..there is already a plugin that integrate solr with nopCommerce. May be you would like to look that one. I've taken a trial and its really dream come true. I ended up using it in about half an hour. It improved speed and search results of my site. You can find more info here: http://www.nopaccelerate.com/