# dot net version of Solr

Tags: iis, asp-classic, solr

We are going to use `Solr` as our search server, but all of our web interface is in ASP, and our data is an MS SQL Server database. What is the best solution? Shall we use Java-based or Dot Net-based version of Solr?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Solr available for .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749314/is-solr-available-for-net)

Comment: FYI - you can always use Solr and use the Data Import Handler (DIH) to pull you data from your database. The ability to push changes directly to SOLR are great, but I just wanted to mention an alternative.

Comment: solrnet is good option !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Solr port for .net, you can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749314/is-solr-available-for-net) to know more. I would use the original Solr written in Java, and  a client library written in the language you prefer, for example [solrnet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/), to communicate with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

Comment: Oh, it was hard to figure in the first place. I've now edited your question and it's much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Solr.Net client](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) or you can create your own client for Lucene.Net like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609980/Small-Lucene-NET-Demo-App). There is no Solr created in .Net available but you can create one since the engine is available in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Best suitable is [solrnet](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) which is up to date with all latest versions of Solr and much mature (minimum issues).